# problem with width/lengh with percentual

Tags: html, css

I have this HTML :

```
<div class="messageQuoted"><a href="#">user1</a> wrote :<br>
    <div class="messageQuoted"><a href="#">user2</a> wrote :<br>
        text1
    </div>
    text2
</div>
```

with this CSS :

```
.messageQuoted{
    background-color:#EAE9E8; 
    width:100%; 
    float:left;  
    margin-bottom:20px; 
    padding-left:10px; padding-top:5px; padding-bottom:5px; 
    border-left:4px solid #333333; border-right:1px #000000 solid; 
    border-bottom:1px #000000 solid; border-top:1px #000000 solid;
}
```

but how can you see on this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/markzzz/gybPP/), the second div with "text2" exit from the the container!

Why? It is 100% (or at least, until the container have space).

Right? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the `div` to be full-width, get rid of `width` and `float` altogether. The default behavior is to expand horizontally.

Comment: Uhm...and using width and float is possible get the same effect? You know, don't know if without putting some attribute ALL browsers do the same effect :)

Comment: @kwichz why do you want to use float in the first place? It doesn't make sense for a 100% wide element anyway, does it?

Comment: @kwichz: You're not making any sense. Are you saying you *don't* want the element to be full-width?

Comment: Ah ok! So I'll put only width:auto; ;)

Comment: @kwichz: `width: auto;` is the default so you don't need that either.

Comment: ;) Other things : if I want to add the same effect to a textarea/input text? Tried to apply a class with width:auto;, but there it doesnt work :) Any tricks?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the box model: `padding` values will be added to the 100% width.

However, a `div` will automatically assume 100% width including all padding if you don't specify a specific width. If you  remove these lines:

```
width:100%; 
float:left;
```

the div will automatically take up all available width.